General term for economic systems such as Capitalism and Feudalism
Is there a general term for economic systems like capitalism, feudalism, and similar systems, i.e. which have something like companies or manors that are owned and/or lead by individuals that are not directly involved in the labour; and where these companies/manors produce most economic activity
Example sentence: "Capitalism and Feudalism are examples of ________"

"general term for economic systems like capitalism, feudalism, and similar systems" Yes: economic systems

@jsw29 I've edited the question to be clearer

Is there a particular theoretical framework that provides the context for what you are trying to say? In a Marxian context, for example, one would say that feudalism and capitalism are class societies, in contrast to communism, a classless society.

I suggest you ask in [economics.se]. This question is more about industry/academic terminology, not the English language in general.

You could call them class systems or stratified systems but that's maybe not precise enough. Is the opposition to anarchism, guild systems, workers' cooperatives and employee-owned businesses (where workers choose management), or something similar?

economic systems: an entire list of them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_system

You could make a case for episcopacy, though that’s more a religious term for oversight. Oversight itself lacks the connotation of ‘ownership by a governing authority’ that you’re looking for. Other terms such as lordship, power or simply ownership also hover in the general area you’re looking for, but I’m not sure any of them lands precisely where you want it to land.

Capitalism and Feudalism are two forms of economic and social organization.

Perhaps they are exploitative systems but it's a matter of opinion.

@Lambie that's an answer

This might be on-topic on Economics.SE    You could try asking in their chat room at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137631/economics

Economic system is a broader concept than what the question seems to be about: only some economic systems 'have something like companies or manors that are owned and/or lead by individuals that are not directly involved in the labour'.
